# Maven says "Cannot find symbol" when trying to build it

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Im trying to build a webapp in jenkins using maven, but it keeps saying that a couple of symbols couldnt be find.

I've checked both JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME, and they are correctly set in Jenkins configs.

If someone knows anything that could help, i'd be grateful.

**The command that i'm running on Maven:**

`mvn clean package`

**The errors presented:**

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.931 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-10T23:03:14-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project marvin: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/luan/Downloads/teste/golden/src/main/java/br/ufrj/info/golden/core/persistence/StudentJPADAO.java:[18,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Student_
[ERROR]   location: package br.ufrj.info.golden.core.domain
```

Comment: I don't see javax.persistence JAR in your dependencies. When you are using your IDE, from where the IDE is finding the relevant package?

Comment: Im using Eclipse. And I'm not sure, but i think those dependencies comes from the repository that is present in the pom.xml

Comment: This is the Java compiler saying that, not Maven. Be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment, if that works in Eclipse but not in Jenkins, then you will have to check:

- That you don't have a local version of an internal dependencies which brings back the required dependencies (if we look at `javax.persistence`, that would be Hibernate/EclipseLink or any other JPA implementation).
- That you are using m2e ("Maven for Eclipse") in Eclipse to import your project and that you did not add a JAR explicitely.
- Since you are in Java 11, that you provides the expected module in your module-info.

To check differences between local and Jenkins, you may wish to generate the dependency tree using `mvn dependency:tree`: that should print your the dependency that Jenkins uses and that your local workspace use.
Using a diff should gives you some hint as to what to do (for example, pushing your change on the internal module so that Jenkins build it before you try to build your project).

In Eclipse, you can also open an offending file, one that does not compile such as `src/main/java/br/ufes/informatica/marvin/research/domain/BibGenConfiguration.java`, go to the import and, while pressing the Ctrl key, click on the class (for example `javax.persistence.Entity`): if you enabled the *Link with Editor* feature of the *Package Explorer*, then you should go to the containing JAR of said class.

If the class is not a in your local maven repository (`~/.m2/repository` or `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository`) then it is most certainly a JAR added to Eclipse but not in the `pom.xml`.

---

[edit] (and answer to comment) My answer was general, not related to javax.persistence only:

When you see such error in Jenkins (or anywhere but where it works), then you need to dig in and check what is wrong:

```
[ERROR] /home/luan/Downloads/teste/marvin/src/main/java/br/ufes/informatica/marvin/core/persistence/AcademicJPADAO.java:[18,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Academic_
[ERROR]   location: package br.ufes.informatica.marvin.core.domain
```

This error means that Java can't find the class `br.ufes.informatica.marvin.core.domain.Academic_` in `src/main/java/br/ufes/informatica/marvin/core/persistence/AcademicJPADAO.java`.

Open the file `AcademicJPADAO.java` in Eclipse, and if its compile, find where it's from, but for those I think that you lack an internal dependency or you have locally a newer version of this dependency (either because you compiled it, either because you update its source code, etc...).

Comment: Thanks, all errors related to "package does not exists" are gone, after adding a lib in pom.xml. Now the only errors to fix are the ones with "cannot find symbol", error log edited.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, there was a internal dependency missing, it was "hibernate-jpamodelgen". After adding it to pom.xml, now works fine!

Answer (score 1):

No `java.persistence` in your `pom.xml`. Maybe you added some extra libs in your Eclipse project's build path. Manage ALL your dependencies via `pom.xml` else you'll always experience problems in your system. Also try `mvn help:effective-pom` in your Eclipse workspace directory and in your Jenkins workspace.

Comment: Thanks, all errors related to "package does not exists" are gone, after adding a lib in pom.xml. Now the only errors to fix are the ones with "cannot find symbol", error log edited.

Comment: I don't know, how many projects you've got and how they are structured. If your project A needs project B to compile, you have to add that project B in project A's classpath. Look at this page: maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Those missing files could also be needed to be generated by some tool. For many of those tools you may find a maven Plugin which you have to include in your <build><executions> section. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag.

Comment: Let's not forget how useful `mvn dependency analyze` can be as well. @janos-vinceller, consider appending to your response? +1

Answer (score 1):

When you try all the methods, don't forget to clean workspace. Sometimes the cache brings issues.